# Mount vue3 on class attributes

Tags: vue.js

I want to mount vue on class opponent.

I have addToCart component that I want it to appear on class attribute "add-to-cart".
I understand that vue's createApp can be only mounted on id attribute and mounting on more than one element will throw an exception.

Is there way to go about this.

Comment: You can mount an app on any element. `mount()` accepts DOM element. It doesn't matter  which selector is used to get it

Comment: @EstusFlask Right! but is picking only one. I want it to pick all classes not only one

Comment: Do you need to create multiple instances? The question doesn't specifically say what's your intention

Comment: @EstusFlask Yes multiple instances. Like I have a class call add-to-cart and I want a component to appear on the class

Answer (score 0):

I did it!

```
const els = document.querySelectorAll(".addtocart");
els.forEach(el => {
  createApp({
    el: el,
    components:{
      AddToCart
    }
  }).mount(el)
})
```